# How to select specific element list

Tags: sorting, dataframe

I want to select a specific value provided by functions.
For example, p-value of `shapiro.test`.
Later to use `unlist`, I get lost in the next step to obtain this goal.

```
set.seed;df<-data.frame(A=runif(1:10),B=sample(0:50,10),C=rnorm(1:10,5));
A<-lapply(df, shapiro.test);B<-data.frame(unlist(A))
```

Comment: I want to know it if is possible to select the value to do loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Column=colnames(df)
for(i in 1:3){
  W[[i]]=A[[i]]$statistic
  p[[i]]=A[[i]]$p.value
}
Finaldf=data.frame(Column,W,p)
Finaldf
```

It is possible to select in the same way presented in the loop.

The result with the method B is:

```
A.statistic.W           A.p.value                A.method               A.data.name "0.861406032778689" "0.0792763017546299" "Shapiro-Wilk normality test"    "X[[i]]" 
B.statistic.W           B.p.value                B.method               B.data.name 
"0.924827600249041" "0.398982034565022" "Shapiro-Wilk normality test"    "X[[i]]" 
C.statistic.W           C.p.value                C.method              C.data.name 
"0.944304879567238" "0.601828906713825" "Shapiro-Wilk normality test"    "X[[i]]"
```

The result after the loop is this:

```
 Column         W         p
1      A 0.8614060 0.0792763
2      B 0.9248276 0.3989820
3      C 0.9443049 0.6018289
>
```